# Bundler cannot load gem rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I'm currently SSH'd into a remote server where I am trying `bundle install`, but here is the message that it spits out when I run it:

```
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?

Gem::Exception: Cannot load gem at [/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.3/cache/rake-12.0.0.gem] in /home2/shsprogr/rails/Frothy-Fox
An error occurred while installing rake (12.0.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '12.0.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

And yet, when I run `gem install rake -v '12.0.0'`:

```
Successfully installed rake-12.0.0
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rake-12.0.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for rake-12.0.0...
```

Yet the same thing happens with bundler above. If it helps, I'm on a bluehost server and I am unable to enable sudo access because [this](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/2358) guide is out of date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're likely going to find several things with Bluehost rails a challenging affair.  You might consider creating a free developer account on Heroku instead.  It will make this process a little easier.

However, you can fix your issue by setting a GEM_HOME in your htaccess file.  This is going to make sure that gems are installed in your web directory of the shared bluehost server - so they won't run into the kinds of issues that require sudo.  So open your .httacess file in your favorite editor and add this line:

```
SetEnv GEM_HOME /home2/shsprogr/ruby/gems
```